# PHP, multiple files upload and gets path of each ones files uploads for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, upload

I found this code, to upload multiple files

http://www.w3bees.com/2013/02/multiple-file-upload-with-php.html?showComment=1390161630156#c8075663254636569559

I modified a little bit the code for obtain a  upload/subdirectories folder with unique id for each one of the sets uploads ;so  the files also gets a unique id.

```
$dir=substr(uniqid(),-7); // Uniqid for subdirectory
$path = "uploads/$dir/"; // uploads/subdirectory/
mkdir($path, 0700); // Make directory
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "jpeg", "kml");
$max_file_size = 2097152;
$count = 0;
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$f], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $uniq_name = substr(uniqid(),-5) . '.' .$ext;
                $dest = $path . $uniq_name;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $dest);
                mysqli_query($dbc, "INSERT INTO files (code, name, path, type) VALUES ('$dir','$uniq_name','$dest','$ext')" );
                $count++; //Number of successfully uploaded file

            }
        }

    }

}
```

This process is carried out correctly.

I want after `move_upload_file`, get all paths(url) of files uploads.
But I get inserted on the database only path first file selected... the other paths files are upload correctly, but not inserted on the database.

Sorry for my bad english, it's not my first language. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something as

```
$sql_error = ''; // add this before you start the loop


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $dest)){
  $qry = "INSERT INTO files (code, name, path, type) VALUES ('$dir','$uniq_name','$dest','$ext')" ;

  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $qry);
  if ( false===$result ) {
    $sql_error .= 'Error in the query '.$qry.'  Error Desc :'.mysqli_error($dbc).'<br /><br />' ;
  }
}
```

Finally add

```
echo $sql_error ;
```

At the end of the file , so if there is any error it will show you the error in the query.

Also by adding the query inside

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $dest)){}
```

means you are adding only if the files are getting uploaded.